# Error while saving a shared Excel spreadsheet: "Errors were detected while saving...."

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I get the following error on my shared Excel spreadsheet when saving:

> Errors were detected while saving "\server......\ Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel."

I have a file on a network location and I'm using a thin client and RDP. All users accessing the file are also on thin clients. The need for sharing is that many users may update the file concurrently and need to see the results of others' updates rapidly.

I've seen mention of this error being caused by the network / remote access and how Excel saves temp files using the local directory, which may not be accessible by the network users. Has anyone come across this problem and know a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried to disable antivirus or verified the permissions on the network share? Does it happen when running Excel as admin?

Comment: It was because this usually causes errors that Microsoft sells Sharepoint.

Comment: I have tried disabling anti virus and checked permissions. It seems to be network related as it works sometimes and other times doesn't work. I'm checking into this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible causes for this error, ranging from Excel bugs (see [KB 2597034](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2597034)) to network issues to anti-virus problems.  Microsoft's KB article [KB 271513](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/271513) lists most of them.  Generally speaking they're temporary annoyances rather than apocalyptic errors.  My personal opinion is that Excel is not really designed for shared use and does as best as it can, but doesn't have the web smarts that Google Sheets or SharePoint would have.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a network issue due to the sporadic errors and not happening all the time. I don't have any images in the spreadsheet. I agree excel is not designed for this, but it's what I've got and need to find a workaround for this project. Looking into network issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a spreadsheet in Excel is very limited, and you cannot do that in the
normal editing mode.

To share a workbook :

1. On the Review tab in the Changes group, click **Share Workbook**:

[image: Share Workbook]

2. In the **Share Workbook** dialog box, on the **Editing** tab, select the **Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging check box.**
3. On the **Advanced** tab, select the options that you want to use for tracking and updating changes, and then click OK.

**Note** : You won't be able to add or change the following: merged cells, conditional formats, data validation, charts, pictures, objects including drawing objects, hyperlinks, scenarios, outlines, subtotals, data tables, PivotTable reports, workbook and worksheet protection, and macros.

For more information see the Microsoft article [Use a shared workbook to collaborate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534).

Comment: Thank you and that was helpful, however, it doesn't answer the question of why saving works sometimes and doesn't work other times, giving this error.

Comment: If you were not in shared mode, someone else was maybe locking the file or the folder, or the share was unavailable. Many things can go wrong in a multi-user environment.

Comment: I was definitely in shared mode. I'm going to test if the file is open but then the network losing connection, if this gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When the Excel spreadsheet is corrupt, you can also:

1. Create a new blank worksheet
2. Go to corrupt spreadsheet
3. Select all the worksheets (Ctrl+Left Click)
4. Right-click on worksheet
5. Select blank worksheet
6. Check on create a copy
7. Click OK

This will help you salvage the data.

You can also compare using a tool like Beyond Compare or Excel Compare, but it can be a bit tricky to analyze data on Excel especially with multiple worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this has 100% worked for me in all situations, if it is a macro file (in my case at least).

Open the file in protected mode (usually I save it on the share network so it prompts me to "Enable Content")

DON'T ENABLE CONTENT

Go to Developer, Visual Basic, then click on "Debug" and click on "Compile VBA Project".

Save the file -- > Close - - > Reopen.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the absurd Excel error message: Errors were detected while saving ... Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features ...

Forced compiling of the VB script, as suggested below, solves the problem!

Excel is usually user friendly but he is very particular about who his friends are.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).